# Indexed view gets scripted without index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I use SQL Server 2008 R2.
In my database exists multi indexed view and multi view that use of these indexed view with hint `NOEXPAND`. When I get script of my database by SSMS (Database\Tasks\Generate Script ... ), SSMS product script by below order :

1. script of indexed view
2. script of view that use of above indexed view
3. script of clustered indexed of indexed view.

When I run created script, SQL server create first indexed view with no clustered index, then want to create view of indexed view with `NOEXPAND` hint, that cause raise error.
What I do?

SSMS error : `hint 'noexpand' on object ..(indexed view).. is invalid.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Search for my question and find method to solve this problem.
this problem appear when you create a simple view named view1 then created another view named view2 then use view2 in view1 then alter view2 to indexed view. 
for solve this problem , you must recreate view1.

Answer (score 12):

The default for scripting indexes is False. You need to change it to true in order to include the `CREATE INDEX` with your view. In Management Studio:

- Tools > Options
- SQL Server Object Explorer
- Scripting
- Table and view options > Script indexes

Set the option to True, click OK, and try generating your script again.

**EDIT**

On a default installation, the above setting is the only thing I changed. I generated the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.x(i INT);
GO
ALTER VIEW dbo.v_x
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT i, c = COUNT_BIG(*)
    FROM dbo.x
    GROUP BY i;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX i ON dbo.v_x(i);
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.v_y
AS
  SELECT i,c FROM dbo.v_x WITH (NOEXPAND);
GO
```

I right-clicked the database, Tasks > Generate Scripts... picked the two views and the table, scripted to a new query window, and this is what it produced (I removed all the `SET` options for brevity, not because they're not there or unimportant):

```
USE [foo]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[x]    Script Date: 06/20/2012 08:03:59 ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[x](
    [i] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[v_x]    Script Date: 06/20/2012 08:04:00 ******/
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_x]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT i, c = COUNT_BIG(*)
    FROM dbo.x
    GROUP BY i;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [i] ON [dbo].[v_x] 
(
    [i] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[v_y]    Script Date: 06/20/2012 08:04:00 ******/
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_y]
AS
  SELECT i,c FROM dbo.v_x WITH (NOEXPAND);
GO
```

When I changed the `USE [foo]` to a different database, the script executed just fine (and obviously things are in the correct order).

So either you're generating the script differently, or you used the "continue scripting on error" option and your view prevents the index from being created.

Comment: I test this method. but SSMS create clusters index of indexed view after of script all views. and if one indexed view use on another view with noexpand hint, when run created database script we face error, that you can't use noexpand hint.

Comment: And that is the *only* error in the entire script? I'm afraid you're going to have to post the script and the method you used to get it. I can't reproduce (updating my answer to reflect this).